# Move folders to the respective sub-folders using the folder name key

Tags: batch-file

I want to move folders to the respective sub-folders if there is at least one word in the folder name that is the same as the subfolder.

I use this code to move files into folders but I need to do same thing to move *folders* into other folders

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            move "%%a" "%%b"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

EDIT: example

I create before theses folders

```
Waking The Dead
Lost.dt%ky
```

I have these folders

```
Waking The Dead s01
Waking The Dead s02
Lost.dt%ky.rang200
```

I want to move these folders

```
Waking The Dead s01
Waking The Dead s02
```

into

```
Waking The Dead
```

or

```
Lost.dt%ky.rang200
```

into

```
Lost.dt%ky
```

Comment: I suggest you choose a different script language where the `%` sign has no special meaning or remove them from file/folder name. Your batch should iterate the folders and move files `"*foldername*"` to the folder.

Comment: what do I change into my script to value a folder instead of a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** 2nd for needs to be a for /f
Try this:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\27\SO_51539948.cmd
@Echo off
Pushd %1
For /d %%A in (*) do For /f "delims=" %%B in (
  'Dir /B "*%%~nxA*" 2^>Nul '
) do If "%%~nxA" NEQ "%%~nxB" Move "%%~fB" "%%~fA\" 2>&1>>Nul
Popd
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front of the Move command.

Sample tree before (renamed `%` -> `_`):

```
> tree
├───Lost.dt_ky
├───Lost.dt_ky.rang200
├───Waking The Dead
├───Waking The Dead s01
└───Waking The Dead s02
```

and after running the batch:

```
> tree
├───Lost.dt_ky
│   └───Lost.dt_ky.rang200
└───Waking The Dead
    ├───Waking The Dead s01
    └───Waking The Dead s02
```